# Spatial Interpolation of gridded data to county data: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, geospatial, spatial-interpolation

I have gridded precipitation information available at 2 degrees monthly.

I need to interpolate precipitation data at each month at each grid points into US county scale. The US here I mean mainland US leaving Alaska & Hawaii.

Comment: Yeah... can you show us what code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you just want to interpolate values from a 2D dataset arranged in a grid?

I think the griddata function is what your looking for.  If not, can you post some example code or some example data for us to take a look at?

griddata function:
http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html